# Dimension of quasi-affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, dimension-theory-algebra

**Proposition 1.10.** *If $Y$ is a quasi-affine variety, then $\dim Y=\dim \overline{Y}$.*

If $Z_{0}\subset Z_{1}\subset \cdots \subset Z_{n}$ is a sequence of distinct closed irreducible subsets of $Y$, then $\overline{Z_{0}}\subset \overline{Z_{1}}\subset\cdots \subset \overline{Z_{n}}$ is a sequence of distinct closed irreducible subsets of $\overline{Y}$.

**Question.** if $Z_i$ is irreducible in $Y$, $Z_i$ is irreducible in $\overline{Y}$? If, yes, why?

Comment: Is your question supposed to be about $\overline{Z_i}$ being irreducible in $\overline{Y}$? I've written an answer to the question as asked, but it's unclear how this is relevant to the proof you quoted.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Yes, in the end I would like to get to exactly this using a hartshorne exercise, but I needed this step first.

Comment: I would like to use exercise 1.6 to conclude what you said, but I can only do it after having observed what was asked, or not? if you could link me your answer?

Comment: My answer (which you can find on this page, below the comments) gives a proof to answer your question in the affirmative: just let $A = Z_i$, $X' = Y$, $X = \overline{Y}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! More generally:

**Claim** Let $X$ be a topological space with subspaces $A \subseteq X' \subseteq X$. If $A$ is irreducible as a subset of $X'$, then $A$ is irreducible as a subset of $X$.

*Proof*. Suppose $A = Z_1 \cup Z_2$ where $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are closed in $X$. Then $Z_1, Z_2$ are also closed subspaces of $X'$, and the irreducibility of $A$ as a subset of $X'$ then implies that $A = Z_1$ or $A = Z_2$. We conclude that $A$ is irreducible as a subset of $X$.

Comment: why $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are also closed of $X'$?

Comment: This follows straight from the definition of the subspace topology -- a subset of $X'$ is closed iff it is the intersection of $X'$ with a closed subset of $X$. Since $Z_1, Z_2 \subseteq A \subseteq X'$, we have $Z_1 = X' \cap Z_1$ and $Z_2 = X' \cap Z_2$.